# Hazelcast Cluster quorum failure and fall back to map store at runtime

Tags: hazelcast

Is it possible to fall back to store and load (MapStore implementation)from persistent store, at runtime if there is quorum failure in Hazelcast 3.5?

Comment: I think it's not possible right now. It's an interesting idea though. Can you please open a new feature request at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new